# Could not locate clojure/core/async__init.class or clojure/core/async.clj on classpath

Tags: clojure, classpath, leiningen

Does anyone know why I'm getting the below error?  I read through answers of similar questions, which recommended using Leiningen, which I've done below and still get the error.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ xxx$ lein new app test
```

Generating a project called test based on the 'app' template.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ xxx$ cd test
MacBook-Pro:test xxx$ lein repl
nREPL server started on port 59623 on host 127.0.0.1
REPL-y 0.2.1
Clojure 1.5.1
Docs: (doc function-name-here)
      (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
Source: (source function-name-here)
Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e
test.core=> (require '[clojure.core.async :as async :refer :all])
**FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/core/async__init.class or clojure/core/async.clj on 
classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)**

test.core=>
```

---

I also tried via cider repl in emacs:

```
; CIDER 0.3.1 (Clojure 1.5.1, nREPL 0.2.3)
user> (require '[clojure.core.async :as async :refer :all])

FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/core/async__init.class or clojure/core/async.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)

user>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add it to your project.clj file.  See the [README](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/README.md) for details for the current version.  Once you make the necessary changes to project.clj, you need to restart the repl.