# Clojures prxml library can't be imported

Tags: xml, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I tried to run simple program which needs `prxml` library like in this [example](http://fasttrackclojure.blogspot.cz/2010/09/lesson-2-clojure-functions.html). Unfortunately, when I do `(use 'clojure.contrib.prxml)` I get

```
FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/contrib/prxml__init.class or clojure/contrib/prxml.clj on classpath:   
clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
```

I am running this in `REPL` on Fedora 18 with these packages installed

- clojure.noarch
- clojure-contrib.noarch
- clojure-compat.noarch
- clojure-maven-plugin.noarch

**EDIT**

It seem to work when I run my REPL through Leiningen with `lein repl`. So what's the difference regarding to that library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not locate clojure/core/async\_\_init.class or clojure/core/async.clj on classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037682/could-not-locate-clojure-core-async-init-class-or-clojure-core-async-clj-on-cla)

Comment: do you have the right dependency set in the `project.clj` file?

Comment: No, I just typed `repl` to open clojure `REPL` environment and entered the command.

Comment: I think you have to put a dependency in project.clj and restart the repl, that worked for me ([prxml "1.3.1"]).  I'm not using repl/linux so I don't know step by step.  That's kind of an old series

Answer (score 0):

I think the "normal" way to do this is to use leiningen, and create a project.clj with your dependencies, and start the repl with that project in effect.  BUT, there is a (deprecated) add-classpath.  Here's a session (under windows shell):

```
PS C:\clojure> java -cp .\clojure-1.5.1.jar clojure.main
Clojure 1.5.1
user=> (add-classpath "file:///c:/tmp/prxml-1.3.1.jar")
WARNING: add-classpath is deprecated
nil
user=> (use 'clojure.contrib.prxml)
nil
user=> (prxml [:root [:hello "add-classpath"]])
<root><hello>add-classpath</hello></root>nil
user=>
```

I got the jar onto my pc in the first place using leiningen.